# Proof that the difference between the input and output of the proximal operator belongs to the subdifferential

Tags: optimization, constraints, non-convex-optimization, proximal-operators

The proximal operator $\text{prox}$ is defined as follows, for a function $f$, at point $x$:

$$\text{prox}_f(x) = \underset{u}{\text{argmin}} (f(u) + \frac{1}{2} ||x-u||^2)$$

The subdifferential $\partial f(x)$ of a function $f$ at a point $x$ is the set of subgradients of $f$ at point $x$, where a subgradient is any vector such that the line generated by it is always under the function.

It is claimed that $\forall x \in \text{dom} (f), x - \text{prox}_f(x) \in \partial f(x)$, yet I can't figure out why.

Comment: Surely the penalty term is added not subtracted? And would it not be the $\operatorname{argmin}$ instead of $\min$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yep, my bad, fixed it.

Comment: Well, at a $\min$ (over $u$), you have $0 \in \partial f(u)-(x-u)$ so you will have $x-u \in \partial f(u)$ where $u=\text{prox}_f(x)$.